# How do I style a ttk.LabelFrame, specifically the background color?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to add some custom styling to a `ttk.LabelFrame`. My code looks like this:

```
root=Tk()
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('TLabelFrame', background='SystemWindow')
style.configure('TFrame', background='SystemWindow')
```

The `ttk.Frame` styling works so I am not sure what is different here.

Edit: Also how can I style the label in the LabelFrame?

Comment: Funny! I just found out 'TLabelframe' works but 'TLabelFrame' not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone that views this line 2 in the code above should read `style.configure('TLabelframe', background='SystemWindow')`. I found a similar question here. Cheers!

[Set style for Checkbutton or Labelframe in python tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755963/set-style-for-checkbutton-or-labelframe-in-python-tkinter)

Answer (score 1):

For someone who just want to set the background color of LabelFrame, You just add your color's code( your can search on google like: grey color code you will get the code: #808080) in background="", this is my code:

```
frame =  LabelFrame(root, text="test", background="#808080")
frame.grid(padx=50, pady=25)
```

Comment: The OP asked about ttk.LabelFrame, not tkinter.LabelFrame..Your code will raise a _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-foreground".

Answer (score 0):

Use f lower for in style.configure(), TLabelframe.

Answer (score -3):

Check all the tutorials related tkinter here. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm

Surely you will get the answer and use Place() method to position your elements in tkinter main frame

Comment: I can't seem to find any info on ttk widgets. All those are just the regular widgets.

Comment: link-only answers are discouraged on this site, and the use of `Place()` (I assume you mean the method `place`) is completely unrelated to what was asked.

Comment: @BryanOakley just wanna thank you for answering my past 2 questions again. Extremely helpful