# How to know all style options of a ttk widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am without knowledge of `tck`/`tk`. I have done carefully search on the internet but haven't found a good solution.

For example, I created a `LabelFrame` using:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
newBT = ttk.LabelFrame(width=100, height=100)
```

Then I need to set the frame style. There is foreground for **`tk.LabelFrame`**. However, I didn't find such style option for **`ttk.LabelFrame`** on [NMT](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/labelframe.html) and [tck/tk](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/ttk_labelframe.htm) reference. Then I have to guess, like following

```
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('TLabelframe', foreground='red')
```

But this doesn't work, [the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755963/set-style-for-checkbutton-or-labelframe-in-python-tkinter) is:

```
s.configure('TLabelframe.Label', foreground='red')
```

So, my question is, how can I find out all the style options a ttk widget has. Is there some function like:

```
s.getAllOptions('TLabelframe')
```

and then the output is something like:

```
['background', 'foreground', 'padding', 'border', ...]
```

Comment: I think I find a solution. First, use `s.layout('TLabelframe')` to find out all elements of this widget. Second, use `s.element_options('element name')` to find out all available options. Unfortunately, I haven't found out how to get **TLabelframe.Label** because `s.layout('TLabelframe')` doesn't output this. It seems not an element of ttk.Labelframe.

Comment: I'm looking for something similar. It seems like one could use `widget.configure()` call, without parameters and get a list of properties in which you cand find the style with its name. Using the name style you can create a tk style and retrieve its color. I'm going to try that way

Comment: Thanks madtyn. You are right the .configure() without argument would tell you properties and current settings. However, that won't give you the style you can set.

Comment: I'm still working for an answer. I have plenty of this done.

Answer (score 22):

I found your question interesting as I had asked myself the same question but have not found time to address it until now. I have written a function  called `stylename_elements_options(stylename)` to do just this. Sharing it here. Hope it can benefit you (although it is 6 months late) and any tkinter users asking the same question.

**Script:**

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

def stylename_elements_options(stylename):
    '''Function to expose the options of every element associated to a widget
       stylename.'''
    try:
        # Get widget elements
        style = ttk.Style()
        layout = str(style.layout(stylename))
        print('Stylename = {}'.format(stylename))
        print('Layout    = {}'.format(layout))
        elements=[]
        for n, x in enumerate(layout):
            if x=='(':
                element=""
                for y in layout[n+2:]:
                    if y != ',':
                        element=element+str(y)
                    else:
                        elements.append(element[:-1])
                        break
        print('\nElement(s) = {}\n'.format(elements))

        # Get options of widget elements
        for element in elements:
            print('{0:30} options: {1}'.format(
                element, style.element_options(element)))

    except tk.TclError:
        print('_tkinter.TclError: "{0}" in function'
              'widget_elements_options({0}) is not a regonised stylename.'
              .format(stylename))

stylename_elements_options('my.Vertical.TScrollbar')
```

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful

Comment: You are a hero for this answer! Very helpful, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, its really helpful. I want to add some thing, for every them the elements are different. if you use `style.theme_use('default')` you will get different Element list and for other theme you will get a different

Answer (score 13):

The issue is that if you really want to control a style in detail you need to use the layout. So first identify the widget class using:

```
>>b=ttk.Button(None)
>>b.winfo_class()
'TButton
```

Then use the command

```
>>> s.layout('TButton')
[("Button.border", {"children": [("Button.focus", {"children": 
[("Button.spacing",
{"children": [("Button.label", {"sticky": "nswe"})], "sticky": "nswe"})], 
"sticky": "nswe"})], "sticky": "nswe", "border": "1"})]
```

Finally change what you want:

```
s.layout("MYButton.TButton",[("Button.border", {"children": 
[("Button.focus", {"children": [("Button.spacing", {"children": 
[("Button.label", {"sticky": "nswe"})], "sticky": "nswe"})], "sticky": 
"nswe"})], "sticky": "we", "border": "1"})]
```

This made the trick for me and finally provides me a way to control my ttk widget!!!

Luca

Comment: This is a good answer to my question. BTW, with `s.element_options()` you can see what options you can set for a layout element.

Answer (score 11):

Building on SunBear's script:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

def iter_layout(layout, tab_amnt=0, elements=[]):
    """Recursively prints the layout children."""
    el_tabs = '  '*tab_amnt
    val_tabs = '  '*(tab_amnt + 1)

    for element, child in layout:
        elements.append(element)
        print(el_tabs+ '\'{}\': {}'.format(element, '{'))
        for key, value in child.items():
            if type(value) == str:
                print(val_tabs + '\'{}\' : \'{}\','.format(key, value))
            else:
                print(val_tabs + '\'{}\' : [('.format(key))
                iter_layout(value, tab_amnt=tab_amnt+3)
                print(val_tabs + ')]')

        print(el_tabs + '{}{}'.format('} // ', element))

    return elements

def stylename_elements_options(stylename, widget):
    """Function to expose the options of every element associated to a widget stylename."""

    try:
        # Get widget elements
        style = ttk.Style()
        layout = style.layout(stylename)
        config = widget.configure()

        print('{:*^50}\n'.format(f'Style = {stylename}'))

        print('{:*^50}'.format('Config'))
        for key, value in config.items():
            print('{:<15}{:^10}{}'.format(key, '=>', value))

        print('\n{:*^50}'.format('Layout'))
        elements = iter_layout(layout)

        # Get options of widget elements
        print('\n{:*^50}'.format('element options'))
        for element in elements:
            print('{0:30} options: {1}'.format(
                element, style.element_options(element)))

    except tk.TclError:
        print('_tkinter.TclError: "{0}" in function'
                'widget_elements_options({0}) is not a regonised stylename.'
                .format(stylename))

widget = ttk.Button(None)
class_ = widget.winfo_class()
stylename_elements_options(class_, widget)
```

Prints the config options as well as the layout tree.

Comment: The real MVP! Thanks a million friend, this is so much easier.

Comment: The Best Answer !