# Configuring all buttons in ttk so takefocus = 0

Tags: tkinter, focus, ttk

I attempted to configure all Buttons in my app to change their takefocus option to 0 by writing this:

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('TButton', takefocus=0)
```

But they still take focus.

Comment: Did you use the style when creating the button ?

Comment: What do you mean? isn't this supposed to configure all buttons? What am I missing here?

Comment: Check this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45389166/how-to-know-all-style-options-of-a-ttk-widget) and run the code for TButton: `print(stylename_elements_options('TButton'))`. You will see `takefocus` is not a valid option for TButton

Comment: So if I want to set the option takefocus to 0, I have to go to every button and modify it separately or is there another way?

Comment: You may be able to create your own button class and inherit from TButton. With that you can set takefocus by default.