# How to change the background color of tkinter ttk.PanedWindow widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, background

How do I change the white colour zone in this tkinter GUI to a different color?

I tried making the change via `ttk.Style`, however, it did not work.

Below is my test code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root['background'] = 'pink'
root.geometry('1200x400+0+100')
# root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
# root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('my.TPanedwindow', background='black')
style.configure('my.Treeview', background='orange', foreground='grey')
style.configure('my.Treeview.Heading', background='blue', foreground='red')
style.configure('my.Treeview.field', fieldbackground='green')

pw = ttk.PanedWindow(root, cursor='sb_h_double_arrow',
                     orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,
                     style='my.TPanedwindow',
                     width=1000, height=200)
pw.grid(row=0, column=0, )  # sticky='nsew')

b = ttk.Button(pw, text='Test ttk.PanedWindow')
pw.add(b)


def create_treeview(parent):
    # Create Treeview
    Cols = ('#01', '#02', '#03', '#04', '#05', '#06')
    tv = ttk.Treeview(parent, columns=Cols, height=2,
                      displaycolumn=['#05', '#06', '#01',
                                     '#02', '#03', '#04'],
                      style='my.Treeview',
                      selectmode='extended', takefocus=True)
    # Setup column & it's headings
    tv.column('#0', stretch=0, minwidth=100, width=100, anchor='w')
    tv.column('#01', stretch=0, anchor='n', width=70)
    tv.column('#02', stretch=0, anchor='n', width=80)
    tv.column('#03', stretch=0, anchor='n', width=75)
    tv.column('#04', stretch=0, anchor='w')
    tv.column('#05', stretch=0, anchor='e', width=80)
    tv.column('#06', stretch=0, anchor='n', width=70)
    tv.heading('#0', text=' Directory ', anchor='w')
    tv.heading('#01', text='#01', anchor='center')
    tv.heading('#02', text='#02', anchor='center')
    tv.heading('#03', text='#03', anchor='center')
    tv.heading('#04', text='#04', anchor='w')
    tv.heading('#05', text='#05', anchor='center')
    tv.heading('#06', text='#06', anchor='center')
    # #0, #01, #02 denotes the 0, 1st, 2nd columns
    return tv


tv = create_treeview(pw)
pw.add(tv)
v0 = ('', '', '', '', 'xxx', str('home'), '', '')
tv.insert('', '0', iid='home',
          text='Hello',
          open=True,
          tag='dir',
          values=v0
          )

root.mainloop()
```

[image: GUI]

Comment: Sorry to tell, but it did work. See the black space between your Button and your Treeview? Thats the panedwindow.

Comment: @Atlas435 So what is the white colour space called? This will help me to rephrase the title of my question.

Comment: The white color zone is part of treeview, not the panedwindow.  Set the `fieldbackground` in style for `"my.Treeview"` and use another theme (some styles may not be supported in current theme).

Comment: @SunBear as acw says its the Treeview. I configured mine with 'default'.

Comment: @SunBear I recently wrote this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69890743/13629335). Its far from complete but gives some input.

Comment: @acw1668 I did specify `style.configure('my.Treeview.field', fieldbackground='green')` and used themes `'default'`, `'alt'`, `'clam'`  but the white space still persist.

Comment: @SunBear As I said set it for `"my.Treeview"`, not `"my.Treeview.field"`. According to [`tkdoc`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_treeview.htm#M82), `"my.Treeview.field"` is not a valid style class.

Comment: `style.configure('my.Treeview', background='orange', foreground='grey',fieldbackground='green')` and `style.theme_use('default')` works for me.

Comment: [In this list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65464537/13629335) its also specified for Treeview, not Treeview.field.

Comment: @Atlas435 your right. Defining `fieldbackground='green'` inside `'my.Treeview'` worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Atlas435 It's kind of strange b'cos when I ran my [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48933106/5722359), `ttk.Style` reports that the `fieldbackground` option appears inside element `Treeview.field`. The tcl wiki you found is accurate. Thanks.

Comment: If this question is cleared, you can either delete or vote to close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As identified by @Atlas435 in the question's comment section, the background of the `ttk.PanedWindow` was indeed correctly set. It is the black space between the `ttk.Button` and `ttk.Treeview`.

The color of the "white space" in the GUI is actually the space controlled by the `fieldbackground` option of the `Treeview` style layout. Although the `ttk.Style()` `layout` and `element_options` methods report `fieldbackground` as an option of the `Treeview.field` element of the Treeview layout, the correct syntax to set the colour of the `fieldbackground` is:

```
style.configure('Treeview', background='orange', foreground='grey',
                fieldbackground='orange')
```

and not:

```
style.configure('Treeview', background='orange', foreground='grey)
style.configure('Treeview.field', fieldbackground='orange')
```

A good reference to defining the `ttk.Style().configure()` statement is to refer to this tcl wiki on [Changing Widget Color](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Changing+Widget+Colors).

@acw1668 and @Atlas435 are credited here to have answered my question. Thanks

I have written up this learning as an answer because I suspect tkinter user will face similar issue and hope this answer can help them shorten/ease their learning curve.

Comment: Please be sure to accept your answer, so that other users know that the question has been answered satisfactorily.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin SO requires a day for the author of the question to accept his/her own answer.

Comment: Huh. Now that I come to think of it, I knew that (I just forgot), but I can't remember if I've ever had trouble with that myself. Is it a day after you post the _question_ (not a day after you post the answer)? That would explain why I've never had trouble with this rule, because I always answered my questions at least a day after asking them. Sorry to bother you about that :-)! I will try to remember this in the future!

Comment: @SylvesterKruin It is a day after posting an answer to your own question.