# How to change the dynamic appearance (i.e. color) of tkinter ttk.Scrollbar?

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, ttk

I have found questions and answers on changing the static colour of a `ttk.Scrollbar`. However, I have not yet found one on changing its dynamic appearance, which is my question.

My [scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48933106/5722359) have exposed the elements of a `Vertical.TScrollbar` to be:

**clam theme:**

```
Stylename = Vertical.TScrollbar
Layout    = [('Vertical.Scrollbar.trough', {'sticky': 'ns', 'children': [('Vertical.Scrollbar.uparrow', {'side': 'top', 'sticky': ''}), ('Vertical.Scrollbar.downarrow', {'side': 'bottom', 'sticky': ''}), ('Vertical.Scrollbar.thumb', {'sticky': 'nswe'})]})]

Element(s) = ['Vertical.Scrollbar.trough', 'Vertical.Scrollbar.uparrow', 'Vertical.Scrollbar.downarrow', 'Vertical.Scrollbar.thumb']

Vertical.Scrollbar.trough      options: ('orient', 'background', 'bordercolor', 'troughcolor', 'lightcolor', 'darkcolor', 'arrowcolor', 'arrowsize', 'gripcount', 'sliderlength')
Vertical.Scrollbar.uparrow     options: ('orient', 'background', 'bordercolor', 'troughcolor', 'lightcolor', 'darkcolor', 'arrowcolor', 'arrowsize', 'gripcount', 'sliderlength')
Vertical.Scrollbar.downarrow   options: ('orient', 'background', 'bordercolor', 'troughcolor', 'lightcolor', 'darkcolor', 'arrowcolor', 'arrowsize', 'gripcount', 'sliderlength')
Vertical.Scrollbar.thumb       options: ('orient', 'background', 'bordercolor', 'troughcolor', 'lightcolor', 'darkcolor', 'arrowcolor', 'arrowsize', 'gripcount', 'sliderlength')
```

**default theme:**

```
Stylename = Vertical.TScrollbar
Layout    = [('Vertical.Scrollbar.trough', {'sticky': 'ns', 'children': [('Vertical.Scrollbar.uparrow', {'side': 'top', 'sticky': ''}), ('Vertical.Scrollbar.downarrow', {'side': 'bottom', 'sticky': ''}), ('Vertical.Scrollbar.thumb', {'sticky': 'nswe'})]})]

Element(s) = ['Vertical.Scrollbar.trough', 'Vertical.Scrollbar.uparrow', 'Vertical.Scrollbar.downarrow', 'Vertical.Scrollbar.thumb']

Vertical.Scrollbar.trough      options: ('borderwidth', 'troughcolor', 'troughrelief')
Vertical.Scrollbar.uparrow     options: ('background', 'relief', 'borderwidth', 'arrowcolor', 'arrowsize')
Vertical.Scrollbar.downarrow   options: ('background', 'relief', 'borderwidth', 'arrowcolor', 'arrowsize')
Vertical.Scrollbar.thumb       options: ('orient', 'width', 'relief', 'background', 'borderwidth')
```

I tried changing the dynamic color of the its thumb using:

```
ss.map("Vertical.TScrollbar", background=[('pressed', "yellow"), ('active', "yellow")])
```

or

```
ss.map("Vertical.TScrollbar", thumb=[('pressed', "yellow"), ('active', "yellow")])
```

but these syntaxes don't work.

I want the scrollbar thumb to change to yellow color whenever the mouse pointer goes over or presses the `ttk.Scrollbar`. How can this objective be achieved? Thanks.

**Sample script(adapted from [@Aivar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46917680/5722359)):**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('clam')
# style.theme_use('default')

# list the options of the style
# (Argument should be an element of TScrollbar, eg. "thumb", "trough", ...)
print(style.element_options("Horizontal.TScrollbar.thumb"))

# configure the style
style.configure("Horizontal.TScrollbar", gripcount=0,
                background="Green", darkcolor="DarkGreen", lightcolor="LightGreen",
                troughcolor="gray", bordercolor="blue", arrowcolor="white")

# Syntax A - don't work
style.map("Vertical.TScrollbar.thumb",
          background=[('pressed', "yellow"), ('active', "yellow")],
          bordercolor=[('pressed', "yellow"), ('active', "yellow")],
          troughcolor=[('pressed', "yellow"), ('active', "yellow")],
          lightcolor=[('pressed', "yellow"), ('active', "yellow")],
          darkcolor=[('pressed', "yellow"), ('active', "yellow")],
          )

# Syntax B - don't work either
##style.map("Vertical.TScrollbar",
##          background=[('pressed', "yellow"), ('active', "yellow")],
##          bordercolor=[('pressed', "yellow"), ('active', "yellow")],
##          troughcolor=[('pressed', "yellow"), ('active', "yellow")],
##          lightcolor=[('pressed', "yellow"), ('active', "yellow")],
##          darkcolor=[('pressed', "yellow"), ('active', "yellow")],
##          )


hs = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient="horizontal")
hs.place(x=5, y=5, width=150)
hs.set(0.2,0.3)

root.mainloop()
```

These are useful documentation [[1](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_scrollbar.html), [2]](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-map.html), on dynamic styling and `ttk.Scrollbar` that I have found. The `tcl` documentation did mention that the dynamic states of a `ttk.Scrollbar` are: `active`, `disabled`. I have tried removing the `pressed` state in my test script so as to only mention `active` state but this amendment did not work.

Comment: Advanced style programming! Good luck. (I was always just happy picking the platform-specific styles...)

Comment: @DonalFellows I managed to crack it... :) tcl documentation helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am so happy to share that the answer to my question is

```
style.map("TScrollbar", background=[('active', "yellow")],)
```

or specifically for a Horizontal scrollbar it is

```
style.map("Horizontal.TScrollbar", background=[('active', "yellow")],)
```

Found it after many different permutations of try and error and after realising my typo. The script used a Horizontal `ttk.Scrollbar` but my styling mentioned `Vertical.TScrollbar`.  :)

Works on these themes `'clam'`, `'default'`, `'classic'`, `'alt'`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style()
# style.theme_use('clam')
# style.theme_use('default')
# style.theme_use('classic')
style.theme_use('alt')

# list the options of the style
# (Argument should be an element of TScrollbar, eg. "thumb", "trough", ...)
print(style.element_options("Horizontal.TScrollbar.thumb"))

# configure the style
style.configure("Horizontal.TScrollbar", gripcount=0,
                background="Green", darkcolor="DarkGreen", lightcolor="LightGreen",
                troughcolor="gray", bordercolor="blue", arrowcolor="white")

# Syntax  - works
style.map("TScrollbar",
          background=[('active', "yellow")],
          bordercolor=[('active', "cyan")],
          troughcolor=[('active', "orange")],
          lightcolor=[('active', "red")],
          darkcolor=[('active', "pink")],
          arrowcolor=[('active', "red")],
          )
print(f"{style.map('TScrollbar')=}")

hs = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient="horizontal")
hs.place(x=5, y=5, width=150)
hs.set(0.2,0.3)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: dynamic]